# Reading of the broken line by Record Reader

Tags: hadoop

I went through the cloudera blog and I got an article(Link below).Refer to the third point.

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/lessons-learned-from-clouderas-hadoop-developer-training-course/

As per my understanding, if there are 2 input splits, then the broken line will be read by the record reader of the first input split.

If I am getting it correct, can you tell me how it does that i.e how the record reader of the first split reads the broken line past the input split ?

Answer (score 1):

> As per my understanding, if there are 2 input splits, then the broken line will be read by the record reader of the first input split.

Yes, this is correct.

> can you tell me how it does that i.e how the record reader of the first split reads the broken line past the input split

An `InputSplit` doesn't contain the raw data, but rather the information needed to extract the data.  A `FileInputSplit` (which is what you're referring to) contains a path to the file as well as the byte offsets to read in the file.  It is then up to the `RecordReader` to go out and read that data.  This means that it can read past the end byte offset defined by the split.